# Expo three rendering on browser but not in device/simulator

Tags: expo, render, assets

i'm new to expo and i'm trying to render a model in react-native using three.js;
In browser it renders and got no warnings, but when you open up the phone I get "Network request failed"

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader'

const HomeScreen = () => {
    
    const onContextCreate = async (gl) =>{
        const scene = new Scene()
        const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            gl.drawingBufferWidth/gl.drawingBufferHeight,
            0.1,
            1000
        );

        camera.position.set(2,2,3)

        gl.canvas = {width: gl.drawingBufferWidth, height: gl.drawingBufferHeight}
        const renderer = new Renderer({gl})
        renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight)
        
        const ambient = new AmbientLight('white', 2)

        const pointLight = new PointLight(0xffffff, 750, 100);
        pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
        scene.add(pointLight);

        const loader = new GLTFLoader();

        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( '/examples/jsm/libs/draco/' );
        loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );


        let cameraOrtho;


        loader.load('./assets/Delta.glb', (gltfScene) =>{

            gltfScene.scene.rotation.y = Math.PI / 8;
            gltfScene.scene.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5)
            gltfScene.scene.add(ambient)

            cameraOrtho = gltfScene.cameras['0']

            scene.add(gltfScene.scene)
            
            console.log(cameraOrtho)

        })


        const render = () =>{
            requestAnimationFrame(render)
            renderer.render(scene, camera)
            gl.endFrameEXP();
        }

        render()
    }
```

I don't know actually what to do, I've tried everything i found on the internet but seems not working for me, thank you!